# Is there any Snippet (GitHub or somethin' else) for Laravel Vuetify server side datatable? With fully-functioned datatable like jQuery Datatable

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I've seen tutorials addressing this issue but there's no example when it comes to the pagination. Unlike the jquery datatable, the pagination buttons are adding with no stop. Could you help me out, folks?

Been asking on the discord community and releasing an issue on vuetify github, got no answer. So I ask it here

example:

<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (goes to 1000) >>

It should be:

<< 1 2 3 4 5 ... 1000 >>

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Pagination Component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/paginations) when doing  server side slicing.

The `total-visible` prop will limit the number of visible buttons.

On the data table, set `pagination.sync` to keep it in line with the external pagination component.

> Used to control pagination and sorting from outside the data table. Can also be used to set default sorted column

```
{
  descending: boolean
  page: number
  rowsPerPage: number // -1 for All
  sortBy: string
  totalItems: number
}
```

Also, set the `total-items` prop.

> Manually sets total number of row items, which disables built-in sort and pagination. Used together with pagination prop to enable server-side sort and pagination

Here's a [codesandbox](https://v8x1rxro85.codesandbox.io/) I put together a while back that demonstrates how external pagination, although it's using Ag-Grid rather than the Vuetify component. Click the cog in the top left to add more rows.

Comment: thank you so much for the enlightenment. never thought there was a pagination component in the vuetify. still dire need of a sample project though... but will be workin' on it based on your instruction. i can't add rows anyway on your sandbox